# Overhang Question

Tags: ultimaker-cura, creality-ender-3

I haven't ran into the issue yet, but I am sort of expecting it to here soon towards the end of my print. Actually, I am not even sure if it should be something that I should be worried about or not.

Basically I have some overhang on a helmet piece (it's a vent piece) and I see that there is a 90 % degree overhang. It doesn't look too big but just curious if this should be something that I should be worried about. I forgot to add support in the vent, it's my own fault and I'm definitely going to fix this in my next print for sure, but do you all think it will fail if I keep the current print going?

[image: Screenshot showing unsupported overhanging vent]

I use Cura, Meshmaker, and I have an Ender 3 printer.

I'm just getting started with 3D printing so I wasn't sure if I should be concerned or not.

Comment: It looks like there are some defects in your STL as well, strange tessellation.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what the geometry of your part is. A picture from another angle as well would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on various parameters if an overhang will work or not, material, hotend temperature, speed, cooling, size of the overhang, etc.

Comment: Awesome, I'll let the print keep going then and see what happens, thanks!

Comment: @Kryreth - what happened in the end? Did it print ok without the support?

Answer (score 0):

Many parameters will influence success. That overhang, as flat as it is and unsupported, will need to have support-structures enabled to become printable.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about that overhang. It should settle in a few layers. Just make sure you have a decent cooling fan on it.
Given the fact that you are making a helmet, I assume you are going to sand and apply putty to the whole thing at least 2 times and then sand in increasing grit. A little filing on that overhang will be an easy task.